# to populate the List box

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, listbox

I am  a just beginner learning OOPS, coding,  ASP.net pretty much the computer stuff.

I have created a WCF service that retrieves the data from the sql database table using LINQ to SQL classes. This WCF service is consumed by the Windows phone 7 application to display data using a  list box.

Can someone help me how to bind the data to  the list box control and to populate the data from the  sql table?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. 
Clicking on button1 listBox1 will be populated with the data using  s = "select * from table where " + s;

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("select items");
       return;
    }
    string s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
    {
       if(i==listBox1.SelectedItems.Count-1)
          s = s + " item='" + listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString() + "'";
        else
          s=s + " item='" + listBox1.SelectedItems[i].ToString() + "' or ";
    }
    s = "select * from table where " + s;
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Comment: This is a dangerous example.  Does the phrase sql-injection ring a bell? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. Ok in this case you are not actually performing the select so nothing will happen but still it is not a good idea

Comment: Thank you. I have four buttons on my page. If I click the first button, the list box populates on a second page ; and if a selection is made, a detail of that item is shown in a text box. Now if I click another button, same thing happens as when the first button is clicked. Now I want the first text box data to be available when I click the second button.How to make this happen? Please let me know.